# An immersion has constant rank in some neighborhood

Tags: differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

Let $f:N\to M$ be a smooth map between two manifolds of dimension $n,m$. If $f_*$, the differential of $f$ is injective at $p$ we say that $f$ is an immersion. I want to show that $f$ has constant rank $n$ in some neighborhood of $p$. I have no idea how to get started. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: If the differential is injective at all points, the rank is $n$ at all points. This is clear, no?

Comment: @Mariano: One is assuming only that the differential is injective at a single point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**HINT**: If a continuously varying $m\times n$ matrix has rank $n$ at some point $p$, show that it has rank $n$ nearby. (Remember that determinant is continuous.)

Comment: Thank you for the hint. But why consider the determinant?

Comment: Well ... How do you determine when an $m\times n$ matrix has rank $n$? (And before you tell me something about echelon form, remember that you want a criterion that you can apply when you "wiggle" the matrix.)

Comment: Isn't it just the dimension of the column space?

Comment: Yes. Now how do you prove that that dimension stays constant when you move the matrix nearby?

Comment: I am still kind of lost. Do I have to show that the determinant of the Jacobian is non zero for a nxn submatrix of the Jacobian?

Comment: That would be useful, yes. :)

Comment: Still hard to see what is going on. Thank you for the help anyway.

Comment: Here I go for the last time. $f_{*,p}$ is injective iff $n\leq m$ and rank of the Jacobian is $n$. That is, the maximal submatrix of the Jacobian with a non zero detereminant is nxn. Since determinant is non zero and is a continuous function, it has to be non zero on some neighborhood around p

Comment: Right, for some choice of $n$ of the $m$ rows.